# Почему не работает моя программа?

Tags: python

Готовлюсь к школьной  олимпиаде и уже на первом задании траблы(
Тут даже скорее не вопрос, а просьба помочь с решением https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZwxUN9oEyrKKMMlaNCrn26PF9Oe-z06H/view?usp=sharing
Вверху первое (ну и все остальные) задания, а вот мой код

```
while True: 
    try:
        n1 = int(input('Минут у первого продавца: '))
    except:
        print('Вы ничего не ввели. Попробуйте снова.')
        continue
    else:
        break
else:
    pass    

while True: 
    try:
        p1 = int(input('Цена у первого продавца: '))
    except:
        print('Вы ничего не ввели. Попробуйте снова.')
        continue
    else:
        break
else:
    pass    

while True: 
    try:
        n2 = int(input('Минут у второго продавца: '))
    except:
        print('Вы ничего не ввели. Попробуйте снова.')
        continue
    else:
        break
else:
    pass    

while True: 
    try:
        p2 = int(input('Цена у второго продавца: '))
    except:
        print('Вы ничего не ввели. Попробуйте снова.')
        continue
    else:
        break
else:
    pass    

while True: 
    try:
        poc = int(input('Монеток у Алисы: '))
    except:
        print('Вы ничего не ввели или ввели символ. Попробуйте снова.')
        continue
    else:
        break
else:
    pass    

def printMax(x, y, z, g, q):
    a = q / (x + y)
    b = q / (z + g)
    if a > b:
        print(a)
    if a < b:
        print(b)
    if a == b:
        print('Они равны(ошибка)')

printMax(n1, p1, n2, p2, poc)

input('')
```

Comment: Да не, работает.

Comment: Ну вот нахрена было именно закрывать вопрос? Автор новичок, достаточно было указать ему на проблемы в его вопросы и поставить пару минусов. Я десять минут писал подробный ответ, а отправить его не могу :(

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Во-первых, у вас входные данные принимаются не в том формате, который описан в задании. Если проверку осуществляет какая-то автоматическая система (а обычно именно так и бывает), то уже на этом этапе ваше решение сразу не зачтётся.

Во-вторых, в вашем решении вы пытаетесь ответить совсем не на тот вопрос, который вам задан.

Почему вообще если стоимости у обоих продавцов равны, то вы считаете это ошибкой? Разве в этом случае Алисе что-то помешает совершить покупку? Вас спросили, какое максимальное количество минут она сможет купить, на этот вопрос и нужно отвечать.

В-третьих, вычисления у вас совершенно неправильные. У вас x - это количество минут у первого продавца, y - цена у первого продавца. Что вообще должно означать выражение `q / (x + y)` ? Зачем вы складываете количество минут с ценой ?

Правильным будет что-то вроде такого алгоритма:

- определить, у какого продавца минуты дешевле
- проверить, сколько целых минут можно купить у этого продавца на все монеты
- убедиться, что у продавца столько минут есть в наличии
- если у продавца меньше минут, то проверить, сможем ли мы на остаток что-то ещё докупить у второго продавца
- вывести общее количество купленных минут

Comment: Я так понял всегда сначала нужен алгоритм. Что ж, буду теперь это учитывать. Спасибо за совет и за ответ.

Comment: @HikkaNote, если ответ вам помог, то на данном сайте принято отмечать его как решение (галочка слева) и ставить ему оценку (стрелка вверх над цифрой слева).